# Invalidate @Cachable entries by annotation on interface?

Tags: java, spring, caching

I'm using `spring` and `@Cacheable` annotation to cache some database entries. I want to invalidate the full cache periodically.

Therefore: is it valid to just put these annotations on an interface method? Or do these annotations have to be placed on class methods (even if they have an empty method body)?

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
    @Override
    @Cacheable("cache")
    Airline findOne(long id);

    @CacheEvict(value = "cache", allEntries = true)
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * *")
    void removeAll();
}
```

The application starts up successfully if I have the `@Cacheable` on the interface method and the `@CacheEvict` in a service. It does not work if I use the code above. But maybe I'm also doing things wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It would probably work, but I'd suggest to put these annotations on the implementation.

It's more of a theoretical question, but think of it this way: **an interface is a common contract, but caching is an implementation detail**.

Your interface could be implemented in a number of ways for example, one day you could have a HsqlDBRepository, for which caching doesn't make sense at all as it's already in memory.

On a side-note, I'd think carefully about why you need to 'evict all'... depending on how often it happens, it could render your caching useless - also it's often a sign of a deeper problem with the design.
If you want to evict entities after some time, consider configuring timeToLive/timeToIdle - most cache backends support this nicely.